# genexus 9 submit

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, genexus

I'm new here. I've got a trouble using Genexus 9.
Is there any way to disable a submit on Genexus 9 (Java + web). Im using CKEditor and I have to save the text in a variable before getting submit and saved on DB, but first at all Im getting submit and then the textarea is empty and I lose what I have write.
Thanks for your help!! Have a nice day

Comment: Could you show us your code a little? I'm not familiar with Genexus at all but it might help.

Comment: Is it a transaction or a webpanel? What is triggering the submit?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the question that you lose the value of the variable, or the moment it is lost.

I give you solutions to common web problems in genexus 9:

1 - The values ​​of web variables are lost if they are not on the page. You have to put them in the form and hide them in a table / div.

2 - Use the WebSession data type to save values. Through events then load or save them.